# Populating a text field based on another text field using Python parsing in ArcMap field calculator

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I am trying to populate a text field 'Subunit' based on another text field 'ACEC_Name'using the python parser in the field calculator (ArcMap). If the ACEC_Name = "Mojave Ground Squirrel" then I want the Subunit field to read "MGS1M." Attached is my code block for field calculator, every time I run the calculator it returns  values for the entire Subunit field (even if they were previously populated). 
[image]

Comment: I don't see any quotes around your return value in the codeblock. It is likely erroring out, since there isn't a variable defined with that name.

Comment: To make it easier for us to evaluate, please edit your question to include the code block formatted as code.